# ¿Como puedo evitar que se escriba las fieldnames cada vez que se ejecute el script?

Tags: python, csv

Cada vez que ejecuto el script se escribe Nombre,Apellido.
Lo que quisiera hacer es que si los fieldnames ya existen en el archivo no se vuelvan a escribir.

```
with open('names.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Nombre', 'Apellido']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'Nombre': 'rodrigo', 'Apellido': 'Gutierrez'})
```

[image: archivocsv]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para no volver a escribir el encabezado del CSV necesitas una forma de
saber si ya está en el archivo y así actuar acorde. Para eso existe el método
*has_header* de la clase *Sniffer* del módulo *csv*. Este recibe una parte del
archivo y devuelve *True* si tiene encabezado, de lo contrario *False*.
Un ejemplo:

```
import csv

has_header = False
try:
    with open('names.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
        has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(csvfile.read(1024))
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

with open('names.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Nombre', 'Apellido']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames)
    if not has_header:
        writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'Nombre': 'rodrigo', 'Apellido': 'Gutierrez'})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.